# Trying to locate files after upgrading to Windows 10

Tags: windows-8, windows-10

I recently upgraded my machine to Windows 10. I had windows 8. The upgrade did not go well so I had to reinstall Windows 10 on my machine. It was a clean install. I had opted to wiping out all the app and user settings. Luckily, when windows 10 was installed, it back all my old files under c:\windows.old\user\ folder. After I installed Windows 10, my account was created as a local account for that machine and I saw all the files existed under my older profile under c:\windows.old\user\

Because it is a work machine, after everything was setup, the helpdesk people created a domain account and changed the default machine and added that machine to company's domain.

Today when i tried to navigate to c:\windows.old\user\ I cannot find any files under desktop, documents, favorites.. etc. folders.

Is there a way to get to the files that were backup under c:\windows.old\user\? I am thinking that because the helpdesk created a domain account and then added the machine to company domain those files still exists somewhere on the machine under different account.

Comment: They should be in the Windows.old folder on the C drive regardless if it is part of a domain.

Comment: Documents, etc. may be acting as symlinks to the current versions of that folder.  Open up a command prompt and change directory to the folder you are trying to view, and do a DIR to see if anything is listed.

Comment: I thought so but did not find those files. Currently i am logged in as domain user. Would that make a difference? I don't think i can log in as a user that was created when i installed windows 10 as the helpdesk has already changed the machine name.

Comment: @Techie007, nothing listed when i used command prompt and dir command.

Answer (score 1):

They are still there but you may not have the correct permissions to view them. If the helpdesk added your domain account as a local user only (no local admin rights) you will not be able to view those files

The easiest way is to logout, log back in using the local account (assuming the did not delete it), copy your files to other location and log back in via domain user

if the local user was deleted you will need to ask the helpdesk to make your account local admin (at least temporarily)

Comment: Tried that. Logged back in as a local user(with administrative rights) for the machine and still cannot see the files. Because the machine name was also changed, do you think that would prevent me from seeing those files even when i log in as local user